# Sim800l doesn't respond to AT commands

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, electronics, sim800

My SIM800L doesn't respond to AT commands. The serial monitor is simply blank.

And the led blinks every 3 seconds which means it is connected to a network

I power it through an LM2596 buck down converter with 4.0 v (I've tried to power with voltages until 4.4v), From a 12v power supply.

Can you help me?
(Please keep in mind that I'm an absolute beginner in this field. Thanks)

I used this wiring diagram from Last Minute Engineers.
[image: my circuit diagram]

And also their code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2 


void setup() { 

    Serial.begin(9600);

    mySerial.begin(9600); 

    Serial.println("Initializing..."); 

    delay(1000);
    mySerial.println("AT");

    updateSerial(); 

    mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");

    updateSerial(); 

    mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0"); 


    updateSerial(); 
} 

void loop() 

{ 
    updateSerial();
} 

void updateSerial() { 

    delay(500); 

    while (Serial.available()) { 

        mySerial.write(Serial.read());
    } 

    while(mySerial.available()) { 

        Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the Tx and Rx wiring carefully. Do the Arduino Tx and Rx LEDs blink?

Comment: Yes. I used the same wiring diagram with a GPS module (minus the resistors) and it worked fine